# Ansible mix roles and apt in one playbook

Tags: ansible

I am just starting out with Ansible and can not find any documentation that discusses using roles and apt in the same book. The playbook I have written is here

```
---
- hosts: apps
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Install distutils
      apt:
        name: python3-distutils
        state: present
    - name: Run roles
      roles:
        - geerlingguy.git
        - mdklatt.python3
        - geerlingguy.nodejs
```

but this gives me the error

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/home/simon/ansible/playbooks/base_apps_server.yml': line 9, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

        state: present
    - name: Run roles
      ^ here
```

Comment: roles doesn't comes under `tasks`. For roles within task use `import_role:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**roles** directive is not a module and can't be used inside a task. See [Using Roles](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles).

Either put **roles** before tasks

```
- hosts: apps
  become: yes
  roles:
    - geerlingguy.git
    - mdklatt.python3
    - geerlingguy.nodejs
  tasks:
    - name: Install distutils
      apt:
        name: python3-distutils
        state: present
```

, or use [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#include-role-load-and-execute-a-role)

```
- hosts: apps
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Install distutils
      apt:
        name: python3-distutils
        state: present
    - name: Run role
      include_role:
        name: geerlingguy.git
    - name: Run role
      include_role:
        name: mdklatt.python3
    - name: Run role
      include_role:
        name: geerlingguy.nodejs
```

Comment: I relatively recently found out about the second one, and I must admit that I prefer it over `roles`, mainly because it feels like having more granular control over when what happens in the playbook. Do you have any preference and reasons for it?

Comment: IMHO technically, there is no difference. `include_role` is more flexible and more complex at the same time. For example, [handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#notes) are available to the whole play. One should properly understand the details of the included roles. Including complex downloaded roles might lead to surprises. On the other hand, properly fragmented roles make life easier. It's a tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pre_tasks` to accomplish this ([see the execution order](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles-at-the-play-level)):

> 1. Any `pre_tasks` defined in the play.
> 2. Any handlers triggered by pre_tasks.
> 3. Each role listed in `roles:`, in the order listed. Any role dependencies defined in the role’s meta/main.yml run first, subject to tag filtering and conditionals. See Using role dependencies for more details.
> 4. Any `tasks` defined in the play.
> 5. Any handlers triggered by the roles or tasks.
> 6. Any `post_tasks` defined in the play.
> 7. Any handlers triggered by post_tasks.

```
- hosts: apps
  become: yes
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Install distutils
      apt:
        name: python3-distutils
        state: present
  roles:
    - geerlingguy.git
    - mdklatt.python3
    - geerlingguy.nodejs
```